# Flask request.form number values are unicode

Tags: rest, post, unicode, flask, urlencode

I have a flask app with a POST request.  When I send the following values in my request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, all values are in unicode when my app accesses them via `request.form`.

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 25,
    ...
}
```

When I access `request.form["age"]` in my app it returns `u"25"` instead of `25`.  This is an issue when I use `jsonschema` validation that is expecting a number.  Has anyone else run into this before?

Comment: All values in request will be as `unicode`. It doesn't matter which values(from query string, form or json). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859650/custom-parameter-validation-with-json-response-for-flask-restful) the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
age = request.form.get('age', type=int)
```

This will convert the (string) age field to an integer for you.

In flask, the .form is of type MultiDict.  The documentation is at http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict